# Add a tag to an AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

What I am trying to archieve;
I want to get a popup with a list of `BikeLocations`. At this moment, my code works.
It works in the meaning of that all `id`'s of my items are ascending from 0 to e.g. 5.
But, when I remove the `BikeLocations`, and add new `BikeLocations`. The `id`'s of these items are not from 0 to e.g. 5, but from 5 to e.g. 10. This means I cannot retreive the `id` of a `BikeLocation` with an `onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)`, because this doesnt return the `id` of the `BikeLocation`, but the index of the array.

```
List<BikeLocation> locations = BikeLocation.listAll(BikeLocation.class);
    final ArrayList<String> arrData = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (BikeLocation location : locations) {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(location.getId().toString());
        arrData.add((id - 1), location.getTitle());

    }
    if (arrData.size() != 0) {
        CharSequence cs[] = arrData
                .toArray(new CharSequence[arrData.size()]);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Selecteer een locatie");
        builder.setItems(cs, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                /*
                 * Locations loc = db.getLocation((item + 1)); LatLng
                 * testLocation = new LatLng(Float.valueOf(loc
                 * .getLattitude()), Float.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));
                 * googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                 * testLocation).title(loc.getTitle()));
                 */
                long longId;
                int intId;
                intId = item + 1;
                longId = Long.valueOf(intId);
                BikeLocation loc = BikeLocation.findById(
                        BikeLocation.class, longId);

                // locatie aanmaken
                LatLng addLocation = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc
                        .getLongitude());
                /*googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                        addLocation).title(loc.getTitle()));*/
                addMarkerToMap(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(),loc.getTitle(), false);

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Geen items gevonden", 10).show();
    }
```

Now, my question is; is there any way to attach some sort of `BikeLocation` id to an item?

Comment: you could use your Dialogs as DialogFragments, then it is easy to add a tag to them!  -->  DialogFragment dialog = new DialogFragment();
   dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyFragmentTag");

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, the dialog can only give you the position of the item clicked.
You can maintain your own lookup array for the id based on position. When you populate your arrData (containing the location strings), populate an arrIds array alongside it (containing the ids).

```
final ArrayList<String> arrData = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayList<Integer> arrIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (BikeLocation location : locations) {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(location.getId().toString());
        arrData.add(location.getTitle());
        arrIds.add(id);
    }
```

Then within the onClickListener, you can get the id with something like:

```
int id = arrIds.get(item -1);
```

(I'm not sure if it should be 'item' or 'item -1'. I forget if the dialog returns the position clicked as zero-based or not...)

Answer (score 0):

If you declare locations as final, you can access that List in your onClick method.  You can then get the BikeLocation directly and not need the id of the location.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            /*
             * Locations loc = db.getLocation((item + 1)); LatLng
             * testLocation = new LatLng(Float.valueOf(loc
             * .getLattitude()), Float.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));
             * googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
             * testLocation).title(loc.getTitle()));
             */

            BikeLocation loc = locations.get(item);

            // locatie aanmaken
            LatLng addLocation = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc
                    .getLongitude());
            /*googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                    addLocation).title(loc.getTitle()));*/
            addMarkerToMap(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(),loc.getTitle(), false);

        }
```